# Need to analyse trend of time series data

Tags: python, graphite, trend

I need to setup a check on timeseries data and report increase or decrease of trend, the data is in form of signal where static thresholding is not working, I have tried polyfit for slope calculation but its not giving correct estimation.

I have been using static threshold for 3 times in a day, because traffic volume change in 24hours(day/night)

[image: & days trend of metric on which I need to setup a Check]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @dyz I need to find out weather the data goes out of trend or not in latest 6 hours. But I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Your "question" (which is not even a question, because questions end with question marks) is way too general. You should read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reorganize your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No trend.**

[image]

Linear fit shows about `-0.011` slope, so you could call it "a decreasing trend", but given a measurement errors and random variation and/or unknown dependent variables - I will dare not to call it so. Very small slopes close to zero is more practical to simply consider as zero, unless it's proven that it's not a random errors source. There are some peaks, but they are not important statistically for a regression. Another argument that there's no trend at all - is that 50 degree polynomial regression shows resemblance to `sin(x)` plot (red line) with a confidence of `74%`. So you can safely report that there is no trend, or that nothing is changing.